# checking presence of lists in a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, instance

I need to check the presence of a list in list of lists. The problem that i face is that my list is composed of class objects and therefore i am not able to do this using the normal 
"if list in list_of_lists" method

the relevant part of my code is as follows

```
for ind in feasible_pop_comp:
    for other in feasible_pop_comp:
        if ind.Type!= other.Type:
            comp=[ind,other]
            if comp not in self.candidate.list #does not work even with .any() or .all() included
                dombool=self.compare_typematch(ind, other)
                if (dombool==0):
                    replace=self.check_distance(ind.point,other.point)
                    if replace:
                        if(ind<other):
                            feasible_pop_comp.remove(other)
                        else:
                            feasible_pop_comp.remove(ind)
                else:
                    self.candidate_list.append(comp)
```

My class already has inbuilt commands to check structural similarities with other class objects(read equality)

```
def __eq__(self, other): 
    return self.point == other.point# as all other parameters are derived from analysing the point, this equivalence is sufficient
```

Traceback is as follows:

```
if comp not in self.candidate_list:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Failed !
```

it loop enters for the first time when the self.candidate_list is empty

As you might notice from my unpythonic code, I am relatively new to python.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "My class already has inbuilt commands to check structural similarities with other class objects" <- have you written an `__eq__` method in your class? If so, you can go ahead with the'the normal "if list in list_of_lists" method'

Comment: i have it does'nt seem to work!

Comment: Show us your `__eq__` method and the traceback.

Comment: if comp not in self.candidate_list:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.point == other.point# as all other parameters are derived from analysing the point, theis equivalence is sufficient

Comment: Not in comments. Edit your post.

Comment: That's a numpy array error message.  When comparing two numpy arrays, the result is an array of bools, which is what the error message is telling you.

Comment: I did realise that. I did a element wise comparison, which should logically work with _eq_ defined, but even that doesnt do the trick.

Comment: @sachiros: but how do you think it should convert the case where the elementwise comparison returns [True, True, False] to a bool?  Should that be True or False?  It's refusing to guess, so it's recommending you tell it by using .any() or .all().  Write your `__eq__` so that it returns either True or False [and, depending on your use case, don't forget to consider possible slight numerical errors.]

Comment: could you go into detail with _my list is composed of class objects_ ? is it the list you search for, or the list that contains the other lists, or both?

Comment: @DSM: currenly my point(defined in equal) contains only only one value. it was the problem of overriding the function as moooeeep suggested. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried overriding the [`__contains__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) method for your container class?
That way you could get the [`in`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#in) operator to work.

But after all, I'm not really sure whether I did understand all parts of your problem...